# Java Draw Image JPanel: Working but weird

Tags: java, swing, drawing, jframe, bufferedimage

I know that everywhere there is a tutoring in how to draw an image. Usually people suggest showing it adding an object that loads that image. But in my case, I don't wanna instantiate a new object every time that I change something in the image.

So, I'm using the Graphics class to do it.
Also, I'm doing it using the MVC approach.

**Problem:**
As we see, there is only a small region of the image that is drawn, if I load another image, this small regions changes according to the picture. Then, I presume that the Buffered image is been load correctly.

[image]

**So, I looking for where would be the problem:
This is my code:**

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DisplayView extends JFrame implements Observer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    private static DisplayView instance;
    private DisplayControl control;
    private JFileChooser fileChooser;

    Panel imageLeft, imageRight;

    private DisplayView() {

        JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        exit.setMnemonic('E');
        exit.setToolTipText("Exit Application");
        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setFileFilter(new ImageFileFilter());

        JMenuItem loadImage = new JMenuItem("Load Image");
        loadImage.setMnemonic('O');
        loadImage.setToolTipText("Loads an Image to Process");
        loadImage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                int ret = fileChooser.showDialog(DisplayView.getInstance(),
                        "Open file");

                if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    System.out.println(fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
                    control.onFileChoose(fileChooser.getSelectedFile()
                            .getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        });

        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        file.setMnemonic('F');
        file.add(loadImage);
        file.add(exit);

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        menuBar.add(file);

        imageLeft = new Panel();
        imageLeft.setSize(500, 500);
        imageLeft.setVisible(true);

        imageRight = new Panel();

        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.add(imageLeft);
        // this.add(imageRight);

        this.setTitle("Test");
        this.setSize(300, 200);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    }

    static public DisplayView getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new DisplayView();
        return DisplayView.instance;
    }

    public void setControl(DisplayControl control) {
        this.control = control;
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (o instanceof DisplayModel) {
            this.imageLeft.setImage(((DisplayModel) o).getOriginalImage());
            // this.imageRight.setImage(((DisplayModel) o).getProcessedImage());

        }
    }

}

class Panel extends JPanel {

    BufferedImage image;

    public void setImage(BufferedImage image) {
        if (image != null)
            this.image = image;
        this.repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.paint(g);
        if (image != null)
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you changing in your image? Couldnt you just modify then repaint it?

Comment: This is just the View of an simple application. So, whenever the image in the model changes, the view get a notification and sets the image again, and after it repaint itself. Right?

Comment: You could do it like that, or you could keep it around and reuse it. Either way would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `Panel` class does not override `getPreferredSize()` and so its preferred size is actually (0,0) and the `FlowLayout` will therefore allocate a size of (0,0) to your `Panel`.

Anyway, I would consider replacing your `Panel` class by simple `JLabel`'s which will do the exact same thing and handle the preferred size for you.

- Calling `setSize()` is useless when you also use LayoutManager's (which you should). In general, simply forget about `setSize/setLocation/setBounds/setPreferredSize`. The answer is always the same: "Use an appropriate `LayoutManager`"
- For custom painting, override `paintComponent` rather than `paint`

Comment: +1, I intiallly missed your suggestion to use a JLabel :) The OP would also, need to `revalidate()` the component before invoking `repaint()` if they continue along the custom painting path.

Comment: @camickr I was about to +1 your answer as well but SO refused because it was deleted ;-). Yes the custom painting path needs many improvements in order to work.

Comment: Thanks for answer.

I was imagining that it could be something with the JPanel size, so I inserted in the code that setSize line.

I did some tests:
1 - I just replaced the JPanel for JLabel - but them, nothing is drawn. Neither that small square of image.
2 - I inserted this line in setImage in my Panel class:  this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()));  - I didn't change my first result.
3 - I comment the line that I'm defining my layout manage, so, using the default one it worked nice.
But, I'm wondering how to use this layout manage, and make it works.

Thks

Comment: @EduardoReis Default layout manager of the content pane of the frame is BorderLayout which automatically stretches the central component (there can be only one central component). If you are looking for more help, consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org). There are dozens of possible issues in your code (is your image correctly sized? does it have anything inside of it? etc...)

Comment: @GuillaumePolet, the image is been loaded correctly. I put a breakpoint and I saw that even thought I set the Panel size to 500x500, it is set to 10x10 somehow. I can insert an setSize in that paint function, but when the windows is being resided is still possible to see that the Pane is draw first 10x10 and after the size that I put on that method.